# Setup a common /opt such that both my Linux Distributions can use it

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I have two Linux distributions: Ubuntu-Gnome and Fedora-XFCE, both having almost the same bunch of apps. Most of my apps are installed in the `/opt` space separately for both the distros.

I have used common installers for both. e.g.: VirtualBox has a "All distributions" file that has been used, for JDK I use the ".tar.gz" file, one more example can be of Firefox.

Now the HDD is running out of space and I want to join the commons in `/opt` drive by storing the common apps in a common `/opt` space and managing the OS permissions to access the folder accordingly. Is it possible to do such a thing?

LibreOffice ia used by me installing it from the respective repository of the application in both the distros separately. I want to install LibreOffice in such a way that the same installation can be accessed by both the distros just as I want to use other above mentioned applications

Comment: Possible, but you'd have to skip all the usual package management on either distro and do manual installs of pretty much *everything* -- and then keep the dependencies sorted and parallel on your own as well. Good luck.

Comment: And what about Libreoffice? Is that possible too?

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense. It ends in a dot, but  that should be a comma followed by something  because it starts out with "if". Please edit your post to make clear what you intend to say.

Comment: Have you considered selecting one of your distros as your 'primary distro' and running the other one in a VM?   Then you wouldn't need multiple versions of libreoffice of virtualbox or whatever because you'd run them on the 'primary' and use the other for whatever distro-specific experimenting you needed.

Comment: The apps that are common to both the distros are
01. Firefox
02. VirtualBox
03. anaconda python
04. Xampp
05. MongoDB
06. JDK
07. Android SDK
08. Android IDE IntelliJ
09. Skype
10. SublimeText3
11. Google-Chrome (stable)
How do I install these applications and softwares so as to use them from a common /opt drive in both the distros?

Answer (score 1):

If under `/opt` there are no installed programs (using `apt`/`yum`) but only self compiled programs you might be able to get away with that. I have been able to do so for multiple Python versions, but I had made sure that the compiler version on the two distributions were the same.

You are probably better of saving space by sharing the VM disc image files (if you don't already do that).

Be carefully to check beforehand if that is going to bring you really that much more space.

Under no circumstances would I "join" installed packages from those two distributions. Chances are  high that you will run into subtle problems. And wasting half a day by first setting this up and then debugging problems should easily pay for a larger/extra/external HDD.

Comment: From the Fedora side, it should be safe to share `/opt`, since by policy we don't allow packages to put anything there. We've reserved the right to use `/opt/fedora` (as provided for by the [FHS 3.0](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html), but aren't currently. Assuming other distros respect that, sharing should be safe. (Of course, with COPRs and PPAs, all bets are off.)

Comment: @mattdm If sharing would imply disjunct directories, the OP wouldn't save any space by storing the common apps there (stated goal). If Fedora's package manager doesn't do so, the OP either must put them there (and make soft links) or compile the apps configured for `/opt/PACKAGENAME`.

Comment: I'm saying that Fedora won't install any apps there or mess with ones that are there. There's no reason to not store common apps